# if if else else doesnt work php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not quite sure what I'm missing here.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        // Makes sure input from uid matches database entry
        if($user == $row['first'])
        {
            if($pass == $row['password'])
            {
                echo "Logged in";
                include "cookie.php";
            }
            else 
            {
                echo "Failed login";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Failed login";
        }
    }
```

This, I believe, is where the problem is, though I can't really tell WHAT the problem actually is. It is meant to give the failed login message when the username ($user) is wrong. I want the page to display the message when either of the two are incorrect. It echos fine when the password is wrong, but if its the username that's incorrect, nothing happens.

Comment: `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` --- the loop body evaluates if there is 1 or more rows found. Presumably when a login name is wrong 0 rows found. Not to say that you don't need a loop here at all.

Comment: Are you fetching all queries or are you fetching just one user?

Comment: I'm fetching just one user, whichever is "like" the username that was entered

Answer (score 2):

Why are you making login process so complex. When a simple SQL Query can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table where first = $user AND password = $pass
```

You don't even need to fetch the record, you can just count & that will do.

this way, assuming you've unique on `first` column in your table, you'll only get 1 row if matches ( authentication successful) and none if it doesn't (authentication failed).
No need to loop & if/else condition blocks.

Comment: Thank you for this tip, I was taught to do it the way I did but your way is better so thanks

Answer (score -1):

You may want to specify a default Message like so:

```
$message   = "Failed login";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    // Makes sure input from uid matches database entry
    if($user == $row['first']) {
        if($pass == $row['password']) {
            $message = "Logged in";
            include "cookie.php";
        }else{
            $message = "Failed login";
        }
    }else{
        $message     = "Failed login";
    }
    echo $message;
}
```

Comment: I've tried to make this work, but havent been able to, thank you though